# Convert image to Blob, javascript, react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I feel that I have a pretty straight forward problem, but I've been taring my hair finding a question that answers it:

I have a create-react-app application.

I have an image in `src/images/image.png`, and I want to, programatically, convert that image to a Blob.

How?

If I render

```
<img src={require(relativePathToImage)} />
```

I see the image.

And if I get it through an input field like:

```
<input
  type="file"
  accept="image/png"
  onChange={(e) => setImage(e.target.files[0])}
/>
```

I get the correct Blob set to `image`.

But how do I bypass doing it manually through the input-field and go directly from
`relativePathToImage` to `Blob`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript:

```
function imgToBlob(url) {
 let img=new Image();
 img.src=url;
 let canvas=document.createElement('canvas');
 img.onload=function() {
  canvas.width=img.width;
  canvas.height=img.height;
  canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img,0,0);
  canvas.toBlob(setLink,'image/png',1) // about toBlob function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob
   }
  }

function setLink(blob) {
 document.querySelector('a').href=URL.createObjectURL(blob)
  }
```

For this html:

```
<a>Blob link</a>
```

**Edit:** You shuld add to the `imgToBlob` function line `img.crossOringin="anonymus"`

Comment: Could there be any reason for the `img.onloadedmetadata`-function never being called?

Comment: I forgot it, the `loadedmetadata` event only the `video` and the `audio` elements has. You should use `onload`. I will fresh the answer.

Comment: Still doesn't seem to trigger? No logs inside the `onload`-function are logged.

Comment: I think its reason the cache (if the browser do not load the image and do not call the onload event).

Comment: Hmm yes, wondering if the image might actually have to be rendered for the onload to be called?

Comment: I do not know... I waited 10 seconds, I have got `img.complete` `true` (boolean, returns `true` if the image is loaded), and got `img.width=0` and `img.height=0`. Something don't loaded, but how and what?

Comment: Solved it! The issue was that I had to do `img.src = require('../images/image.png');` if I do `img.src = require(path);`, where `path` is holding the URI nothing happens. and if I do `img.src = path;` then `img.onerror` is triggered instead of `img.onload`.

Also, apparently it's recommended to do `img.src = ...` after defining `img.onload = ...` to avoid possible race-condition.